# How to escape double bracket (bash ternary if inliner) in Markdown for GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown

How do I escape double bracket [[ in bash inliners:

```
[[ -d /w ]] || (_user=${USER};sudo mkdir /w;sudo chown ${_user} /w;chmod 700 /w)
```

so that Markdown

````
``` bash
[[ -d /w ]] || (_user=${USER};sudo mkdir /w;sudo chown ${_user} /w;chmod 700 /w)
```
````

for GitHub won't produce

```
 -d /w
```

only?

Surrounding lines in GitHub's wiki page:

...

2. text text text text text ...
   **TODO:** edit page to see inliner containing bash ternary if

   `bash
   [[ -d /w ]] || (_user=${USER};sudo mkdir /w;sudo chown ${_user} /w;chmod 700 /w)`
3. text text text text ...

...

The line is displayed properly when previewed, but committed source produces a "-d /w" string only (in a frame, as usual).

Comment: This works for me just fine; where doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @BenjaminW. No clue. It simply doesn't. Strange enough, so I've posted the question.

Comment: I mean, in what context? A readme.md in a project? A comment field?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Project's wiki page's source.

Comment: Works for me as well if I use just the one line. Maybe post the lines surrounding this one?

Comment: @BenjaminW. question edited - added info

Comment: Can you access this chat room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102911/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-marek-cupak

Comment: And if not, can you post the link to that wiki page so I can see the original markdown? It still works for me and I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Benjamin, thank you for your interest, but I can't really let you see the whole source, as it is internal corporate page. But I can access mentioned chat room.